# mysqldump with INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I want to merge data from one database to another. So I create dump with `mysqldump` and then import it to another database (with same tables structure). I don't have any problems (such as duplicate entries or something else) in this case.

But I do some merges for testing purposes and I'll do final merge later. So, I want to execute merge (data may be changed) a few times. Notice, my rows in my tables never deletes, only can be inserted or updated.

Can I create mysqldump with ON DUPLICATE option? Or may be I can merge dump that inserts new data and update modified data?

Sure, I can insert `ON DUPLICATE` in dump manually, but I want to automate merge process.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are options to help you in this:

```
  --insert-ignore     Insert rows with INSERT IGNORE.
  --replace           Use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO.
  -t, --no-create-info
                      Don't write table creation info.
```

Keep this paradigm in mind

- mysqldump everything from DB1 into DUMP1
- load DUMP1 into DB3
- mysqldump everything from DB2 using --replace (or --insert-ignore)
  and --no-create-info into DUMP2
- load DUMP2 into DB3

Comment: Wait a minute: using --replace means that DB2 data will overwrite DB1 data, and using --insert-ignore means that DB1 data prevails.  The question seems to ask how to do *UPDATE* in the case of duplicate keys.  In any case, I'd like to know.

Comment: @EdwardNewell Please note that `--replace` is equivalent to doing `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` on every column. Unfortunately, mysqldump is not designed to update specific columns because of the bulk loading and dumping nature of mysqldump. My answer simply reveals what mysqldump is capable of doing. You would have to write custom code, apart from mysqldump, to do `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`.

Comment: As long as DB1 and 2 have exactly the same schema, you're right.  But suppose DB1 has extra fields. Then --replace will cause the extra fields to revert to defaults (or an error if there are no defaults) instead of just updating the shared fields.  I realize the OP's situation is for two databases with the same schemas, but just pointing out that there *is* a difference, and it would be useful to have a true update-type dump in certain cases (I'm facing one now!)

Comment: Since the question specifically says `import it to another database (with same tables structure)`, then my answer matches the question as posed. In the event of updating a few columns instead of all columns (regardless of matching table structures or not), you have to custom code `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. mysqldump is definitely not the solution in your particular case. I recommend that you post your problem as a separate question.

Comment: Note that if there are foreign keys pointing to the record being updated, using `REPLACE INTO` might fail because the record cannot be deleted with severing those relationships. If you have `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then you will empty-out those tables that depend upon the one being updated. `REPLACE INTO` is quite a dangerous operation.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz this is why mysqldump is not the solution for everyone. The mysqldump options for replace and insert ignore are not got the faint of heart but are for those who truly know their effects and can live with the data thereafter. Mysqldump is never to thought of as a replacement for custom data manipulation, nor is it a panacea for every DB setup. Custom scripting of bulk loading is the safest and most responsible approach by far

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Agreed. I just wanted to comment so that anyone reading this answer understood that these options (particularly `REPLACE INTO`) can be dangerous and have "surprising" effects. Good answer -- just wanted to add a caveat.

Comment: been in need of this for a long while now. thumbs up